# Swift: How to assign a value to a variable inside an array?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, loops

I Have had quite some trouble with what is likely a beginners question in Swift:

I am trying to save some high scores to variables that I want to permanently save - based on the selected game type and game difficulty.

Preferably this should be done using a loop since in my actual code there will be many different game/difficulty combinations, so an if statement would get quite large. What I tried to do looks somewhat like this (the part where I don't know what to do is marked with a comment):

```
var hiScoreEasyA = 0
var hiScoreHardA = 0
var hiScoreEasyB = 0
var hiScoreHardB = 0

var currentGame = "A"
var currentDifficulty = "Easy"

var currentScore = "9999"

var newHiScore = false

func setHiScore() -> Void {
    var hiScores: [[Any]] = [
        ["A", "Easy", hiScoreEasyA],
        ["A", "Hard", hiScoreHardA],
        ["B", "Easy", hiScoreEasyB],
        ["B", "Hard", hiScoreHardB]   
    ]

    for hi in hiScores.indices {
        if (hiScores[hi][0] as! String) == currentGame && (hiScores[hi][1] as! String) == currentDifficulty {
            if (hiScores[hi][2] as! Int) < currentScore {
                newHiScore = true
                //Here I would need to assign the value of currentScore to the variable stored in hiScores[hi][2] (hiScoreEasyA)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The code seems to work so far but I have not found any practical way to assign the current score to the correct high score variable.

Any ideas how to tackle this? I'd appreciate the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are on the wrong path. If your game has many difficulties and game types, then you should get rid of these variables:

```
var hiScoreEasyA = 0
var hiScoreHardA = 0
var hiScoreEasyB = 0
var hiScoreHardB = 0
```

and replace them with a dictionary that maps each high score category to the high score. A "high score category" is simply a difficulty and a game type combined, e.g. "easy A", "hard B":

```
struct HighscoreCategory: Hashable {
    let difficulty: String
    let gameType: String
}
```

The dictionary looks like this:

```
var highScores = [
    HighscoreCategory(difficulty: "Easy", gameType: "A"): 0,
    HighscoreCategory(difficulty: "Hard", gameType: "A"): 0,
    HighscoreCategory(difficulty: "Easy", gameType: "B"): 0,
    HighscoreCategory(difficulty: "Hard", gameType: "B"): 0,
]
```

Now to set the high score of the current game type and difficulty, you don't need any loops at all! You just do

```
func setHiScore() -> Void {
    let highScoreCategory = HighscoreCategory(difficulty: currentDifficulty, gameType: currentGame)
    let previousHighscore = highScores[highScoreCategory] ?? 0
    if previousHighscore < currentScore {
        newHiScore = true
        highScores[highScoreCategory] = currentScore // this is the line where you set it
    }
}
```